# Создание списка и переход на новую Activity

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, listview, adapter

Вопрос заключается в том, как перейти на новые Activity по нажатию на элемент в списке? Пробовал использовать listView и recyclerView и использовать адаптеры, но так как я совсем недавно занялся программированием, то это сложно для меня. Есть ли еще варианты как создать большой список из элементов, а именно изображения и названия, что бы при нажатии на определенный элемент открывалось определенное Activity(для каждого элемента из списка свое Activity)? Или кто то сможет написать адаптер для listView или recyclerView?

Comment: На котлине запуск активити по клику в одну строку можно сделать: `view.setOnClickListener { view.context.startActivity(view.context, ActivityClass::class.java) }`. Этот код надо в onBindViewHolder прописать для RecyclerView или в аналоге для ListView. Написать вам весь код будет сложно, т.к. надо очень долго выяснять все нюансы, т.е. подробное ТЗ составлять. Такое мало кому интересно, а дел тут, на самом деле, на 5 минут (в смысле написания кода), если чётко знать что именно сделать надо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать нечто подобное:

```
public interface AdapterOnClickListner{
    void onItemClick(int itemId);
}
```

Передавать этот интерфейс в конструктор Вашего адаптера и вызывать по нажатию кнопки или любого элемента

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>{
    AdapterOnClickListener mListner;
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position){
       holder.button.setOnClickListener(v -> mListener.onItemClick(holder.itemView.getId()))
 }
}
```

И имплементировать этот интерфейс в активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterOnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int itemId){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```